# c# 4.0 wpf html decode is not correctly decoding special characters - System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-encode, string-decoding

The text i am trying to decode **Anasayfa > OEM Ürünleri > Ekran Kartları > SAPPHIRE**

Alright this is how i am trying

```
 string srCategory = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(nodeCategory.InnerText.ToString()).ToString().Trim();
```

The result: **Anasayfa > OEM �r�nleri > Ekran Kartlar� > SAPPHIRE**

So why it is not working ? thank you.

c# 4.0 wpf application

Comment: You have the wrong encoding.  What's the original string?

Comment: this is the original string : Anasayfa > OEM Ürünleri > Ekran Kartları > SAPPHIRE . i am using htmlagility pack to load web page.

Comment: That's not HTML encoded.  You're probably loading the webpage with the wrong encoding in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me. 
This is correct, no?

```
string srCategory = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("Anasayfa > OEM Ürünleri > Ekran Kartları > SAPPHIRE").ToString().Trim();
```

My current culture is EN-US, whats yours, I can try to duplicate and update here although I really don't think that matters here at all.

Are you certain its just not a display issue in whatever you are trying to display? Its not an encoded character so it shouldn't change upon decode.

Comment: no when i assign the value to the label still incorrect. the text page is this : http://www.vatanbilgisayar.com/Ekran%20Kart%C4%B1/sapphire-11167-02-20r-hd5570-gddr3-1gb-128bit-ati-dx11-ekran-karti-%2811167-02-20r%29/productdetails.aspx?I_ID=43725  . i am using htmlagilitypack to download and select the category title.

Comment: i even tried this but still problematic :             StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text).GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8); //put your encoding

Comment: setting encoding to iso iso-8859-9 fixed.